# Dart remove item form list if value equal other value

Tags: flutter, dart, in-app-purchase

Hi i have list `List<ProductDetails>` like that i want remove item if price value equal others

1 Gold 1$
5 Gold 1$
10 Gold 1$

```
ProductDetails(
      {@required this.id,
      @required this.title,
      @required this.description,
      @required this.price,
      this.skProduct,
      this.skuDetail});
```

I want to remove 1 gold and 5 gold just show 10 gold how can i do it ?

Im sorted list like that

```
List<ProductDetails> _productsSorted = _products
      ..sort((a, b) => a.price.compareTo(b.price));
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you please make your question more clear. If you want you can write in Turkish language also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all import collection library;

```
import "package:collection/collection.dart";
```

secondly use groupBy method to group your list item by price;

```
Map<dynamic, List> _grouped = groupBy(_products, (p) => p.price);
```

at last make a new list from the first item of the each value of the `_grouped` Map;

```
List _lastList = [];

_grouped.values.forEach((f) => _lastList.add(f.first));
```

Comment: your answer should be in english.

Comment: why :).... I am just kidding. I'll write in English after the problem is being solved. Just wait :)

Comment: Tamamdır. Şimdi çözüyorum :) problemi

Comment: ister first kullan ister last, çok da bi önemi yok, önemli olan sadece bir eleman almak. Cevabı puanlamayı da unutma ve `groupBy` kullanımı hakkında biraz alıştırma yap, bir çok yerde hayat kurtarır :)